# Renaming pins in sketch

Tags: pins, datalogging

I'm trying to rename pins so that they post as some kind of alpha-numeric combination in a database.  For example, if I define the following....

```
#define APLHA 0
#define BRAVO 2
#define CHARLIE 5
#define DELTA 6
```

...I would like to rename the output of the pins, as recorded in the db, as something other than 0, 2, 5, and 6 (or whatever pin is used). Let's say A, B,C, and D for the purposes of this exercise.

Is this just as simple as creating if() function that is called upon prior to posting to the db (ex. if 0 then A, if 2, then B, etc)?  I feel like there must be a better, dare I say more elegant(?), way of doing this?

Current output:
PIN | VALUE
0  |   1
 2  |   1
 5  |   0
 6  |   0

Desired:
PIN | VALUE
 A  |   1
 B  |   1
 C  |   0
 D  |   0

Comment: `I would like to rename the output of the pins, as recorded in the db` - I don't understand this, sorry. You can give pins names, as in your list of defines. What is the issue here?

Comment: Why not record the names in the database and let the database do the databasing instead.

Comment: Sounds like I'm overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
static const byte PIN_NUMBER[4] = { 0, 2, 5, 6 };
static const char *PIN_NAME[4] = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

// and use them like this:

void Log(byte index)
{
  byte val = digitalRead(PIN_NUMBER[index]);
  Serial.print(PIN_NAME[index]);
  Serial.print('|');
  Serial.println(val);
}

void setup()
{
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i) pinMode(PIN_NUMBER[i], INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("PIN|VALUE");
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i) Log(i);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Also, in the special case of "A", "B", "C", "D" as pin names, you don't really need the `PIN_NAME` array, instead of

```
Serial.print(PIN_NAME[index]);
```

you can use:

```
Serial.print('A' + index);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you.  I'll try it and report back but this looks to be the solution.